# Multi input with ngFor in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First my English is bad, so I try to explain as best as possible, my problem is this:

I have this ngFor, applied to an Input, but when entering data, it repeats the same in all the fields and I do not find my problem.

```
      <div *ngFor="let itra of itras; let n=index " class="col-md-4">
        <input type="number" name="{{n}}" #{{n}} [(ngModel)]="ihi.Itra[n]"  [attr.placeholder]="itras[n]"  class="form-control" max="999999">
      </div>


      import {Ihi} from '../models/ihi';
      export class AddDocumentsComponent implements OnInit {
      public ihi: Ihi;
      public itras = ["1", "2", "3"];
```

Angular model:

`export class Ihi{
    constructor(
        public _id: string,
        public Idoc: string,
        public Fech: string,
        public Hini: string,
        public Hter: string,
        public Luga: string,
        public Itra: string
    ){}}`

They are sent to an api made with MEN

```
var ihiSchema = Schema({
  Idoc:{type: Number},
  Fech:{type: String},
  Hini:{type: String},
  Hter:{type: String},
  Luga:{type: String},
  Itra:[{type: Number,minlength:6,maxlength:6}]},{versionKey: false});
```

In the tests with postman the api receives several parameters "Itra", but I can not do the same with angular. I appreciate the help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `[(ngModel)]="ihi.Itra[n]"`? According to your model you are binding elements to different chars in the same string. Probably you should use `[(ngModel)]="itras[n]"` or if you have array of `Ihi` objects `[(ngModel)]="ihi[n].Itra"`

Comment: I only want to have 5 input, which when adding different digits in each, save them in the array "Itra" that I have in my api. If I take `[(ngModel)]="ihi[n].Itra"` it does not work for me

Comment: In that case, you should have `<div *ngFor="let itra of itras; let n=index " class="col-md-4">
        <input type="number" name="{{n}}" #{{n}} [(ngModel)]="itras[n]"  [attr.placeholder]="itras[n]"  class="form-control" max="999999">
      </div>` and `public itras = ["1", "2", "3","4","5"]; `

Comment: If I change the `[(ngModel)]="ihi.Itra" `  by `[(ngModel)]="itras[n]" `, it does not send the data to the DB, and the entry of numbers in the input works poorly.
I know that the error should in ngModel, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead? Not sure what your are trying to accomplish with the input, but ngModel and name field needs to match

```
  <div *ngFor="let itra of itras; let n=index " class="col-md-4">
    <input type="number" name="itra" [(ngModel)]="itra"   class="form-control" >
  </div>
```

Also remember to `import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';` in app.module

Comment: And I have added import {FormsModule} from '@ angular / forms';